# Raster update error when saving heatmap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapbox, tilemill

I am using QGIS and I recently added a delimited layer and all my coordinates appear fine , however when I add a heatmap I get the error "Raster update error: Could not open the created raster for updating. The heatmap was not generated."

I am confident that I have added me heatmap correctly by specifying a valid output path and saving as .tiff as I previously done in the past but for some reason now I am getting this error . After some research some indicated that it might be bug  or something wrong with the plugin

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be some sort of bug because after closing down and restarting QGIS the heatmap plugin now works perfectly again .